# Sequence diagram advice

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have an analysis exam tomorrow and one of my designs is a sequence diagram. I do not know if I have got it right. Its pretty simple, its supposed to illustrate a teacher who creates an assignment and posts it to a schools website, then a student gets a notice and the teacher is able to edit or add more files to the assignment. Repeat

[image]

Is it something wrong with this diagram? What could I have changed? 
What are some key points about sequence diagram that I could say in my oral exam.

Comment: Looks ok. WRT your exam: be prepared, that's all you need.

Comment: For me, the diagram is a functional illustration of a use case, because in your case you get at least the web browser of the student which receive "something" to update the page. It could be a push, a websocket,or at least something. Your diagram does not have return message, that's strange for me but if you do not model the code, that's could be.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, what you draw is NOT a sequence diagram in UML spec. There are more than one correct ways to draw a sequence diagram for a given flow.

Here is a sequence diagram I created with [ZenUML](https://www.zenuml.com) (I created this tool btw). There are a few key items in a sequence diagram - `lifeline`, `message` and `fragment`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer is certainly late for the exam, but your diagram looks ok. For the sake of completeness, here some minor remarks:

- the messages are certainly all [asynchronous](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#asynchronous-call) (i.e. the website will not wait for the student to answer the notification before it continues its job); so the arrows should have an open head
- you could consider using a [combined fragment](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html) (with operator `loop`) around the interactions related to the addition of a file, to show that this part may be repeated.
- all messages in your diagram describe inter**actions**.  The wording "web page is updated" suggests a state, whereas a wording "notify student of the update" would be more consistent with the rest.
- the first [execution occurence](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#lifeline) ("activation bar" on the lifeline) on the website should start with the incoming message that triggers the related activity.  Similarly, for the student I'd put a small activation bar after each notification, instead of a continuous one.